# How to test a static function with an interface as a parameter?

Tags: c#, interface, static-classes

I have seen a code, but I don't know how to set the `IPoint2D Start` and `IPoint2D End` which are the GetAngle method's parameters?

```
public interface IPoint2D
{
        int mX { get; set; }
        int mY { get; set; }

        void Set(int X, int Y);
        string ToString();
}
public static class GeometryAlgorithm
{
   public static double GetAngle(IPoint2D Start, IPoint2D End)
  {
        return Math.Atan((End.mY - Start.mY)/(End.mX - Start.mX)) / Math.PI * 180.0f;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're not testing the interface. You're testing the method. I'd suggest creating a test implementation (or mock) that returns known X and Y values for `Start` and `End`, then call `GetAngle`. Check the result is correct.

Comment: You do not need to "_test an interface_", you need to test a function that has an interface as a parameter. That being said, an interface is just a promise, a contract, on what will have a type, you should implement that interface in a class.

Comment: this might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define a class implementing this interface. Here is demo code

```
class Point2D : IPoint2D
{
    public int mX
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int mY
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Set(int X, int Y)
    {
        mX = X;
        mY = Y;
    }
}
```

Now you can create instances of this class and pass it to `GetAngle` method.

```
Point2D start = new Point2D() { mX = 10, mY = 10 };
Point2D end  = new Point2D() { mX = 20, mY = 20 };
GeometryAlgorithm.GetAngle(start, end);
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could also `IPoint2D start = new Point2D()...`

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces represent a contract between objects. If you want to test your interface you need to create an object that implements the interface.

If you change your `IPoint2D` to `Point2D`:

```
    public class Point2D
    {
        int mX { get; set; }
        int mY { get; set; }

        public Point2D(int x, int y){
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

    }
```

Then you could use it like so, as long as you also update your static function to take objects of type `Point2D`:

```
    //...

    var start = Point2D(0,0);
    var end = Point2D(10,10);

    var angle = GeometryAlgorithm.GetAngle(start,end);

    //...
```

If you wish to keep it as an interface, you'll have to have it implemented in a class like so:

```
    public class Point2D : IPoint2D
    {
        int mX { get; set; }
        int mY { get; set; }

        public Point2D(int x, int y){
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        void Set(int x, int y) {
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
           return $"X: {mX}; Y: {mY}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, having interfaces is not wrong. OP should not modify the interface, your class does not implement the interface. It should `public class Point2D : IPoint2D`

Comment: Who said interfaces were wrong? Also, they were asking how to test an interface with a static class, which you can't do unless you implement it. I was showing them how they could test their static method without an interface.

Comment: Good point I'll add that to clarify